# BigInteger in Java

Tags: java

I try using BigInteger like this (where m and n are integers):

```
m.substract(BigInteger.ONE), n.substract(BigInteger.ONE)
```

it says: "cannot invoke subtract(BigInteger) on the primitive type int"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Trying to invoke `subtract(BigInteger)` on the primitive type `int`.

Comment: int is a primitive type. you have to wrap your values into the Integer class

Answer (score 7):

`int` is a native datatype, it is **not** an object!!!

Maybe you should declare `m` and `n` as `BigIntegers` instead?

Comment: it says the method subtract(BigInteger) is undefined for the type Integer

Comment: thats because it is only defined in the class `BigInteger`, so m needs to be of the type `BigInteger`

Comment: `int`s are not objects so they don't have methods at all. In some cases, java will auto-box an `int` to `Integer`. `Integer` doen't have (or need) a subtract method. When subtracting `int`s you use the `-` operator, for example `m - n`. The `-` operator only works on native data types. When subtracting `BigInteger`s you use the `subtract` method which only works on other `BigInteger`s.

Answer (score 4):

m.substract(BigInteger.ONE)  here m is only an `int` it is neither a `BigInteger` nor an `Object` of any kind, but a primitive. If you want to call a method (`substract(BigInteger i)`) then m and n need to be an `Object` of some `class` that actually has the method `substract(BigInteger i)`.

You could do it like this:

```
BigInteger mBig = new BigInteger(m);  // in this case n is a String
mBig = mBig.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
```

BTW: it is called **subtract** and not substract (without the s)

Comment: `BigInteger` is immutable so the second line doesn't do anything, you need to reassign `mBig` to the result. Nice spot on the "substract".

Answer (score 0):

`int`s are primitive times, they do not have methods.
The boxed type, `Integer` doesn't have a `subract(BigInteger)` method either.

You need to either make the `int`s into `BigInteger`s with `BigInteger.valueOf` or make the `BigInteger`s into `int`s with `intValue`.

The latter approach is unsafe as the `BigInteger` may be bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

So you need to do

```
BigInteger.valueOf(m).subtract(BigInteger.ONE),
BigInteger.valueOf(n).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
```

But this is a little messy so why not do

```
BigInteger.valueOf(m - 1), BigInteger.valueOf(n - 1)
```